How to restore auto zoom level in Hyper-V VM window?
I used View -> Zoom Level -> 25% on my Hyper-V VM window to move it away into a corner, but now I can't restore it as the View menu is no longer displayed.
How do I reset it to auto or 100%?

Find the ZoomLevel value in this file and change it to 100:
%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Client\1.0\vmconnect.config
